# FileUpload from primeng 16.3.1 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I try to use the advanced example from [advanced](https://primeng.org/fileupload#advanced)
But I'm running into a lot of problems, the example just doesn't work for me and I'm trying to find the reasons. I have Diamod-ng template when adding a new component I got errors, then I decided to create a new project and install primeng

```
ng new project

npm install primeng
```

I added the modules indicated in the manual,

The first error was:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

I solved that error by creating a variable of type number in the component but then I got this other error:

```
Argument of type 'FileUploadEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UploadEvent'.
```

They are the same errors that I get when I use the template.
I compared my project with that of stackblitz I checked the versions, I copied the dependencies to my project but I still get the error.

My operating system is windows 11
Angular: 16.2.0
Node: 18.17.0
npm: 9.6.7
primeNG: 16.3.1

I would like to know if anyone else experienced this problem or maybe I should update a component that is affecting PrimeNG.